# Java Graphics method drawImage doesnt work with 'this' as ImageObserver what can I do?

Tags: java, applet

I'm pretty new about java programming and just following a guide about programming a small game in Java. So I have to draw an Image with the drawImage method from the Graphics class. I've overwritten the paint method and tried to call the g.drawImage(myImage/*Instance of Class Image*/, character.getX, character.get, this). Now Eclipse say I need a ImageObserver what I think is right but I thought when I overwrite the method and take as Argument an Instance of the Graphics (here named g) class then this is a reference for g and this is my ImageObserver.

```
package Game;

import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.net.URL;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.image.ImageObserver;

public class MainGame extends Applet implements Runnable, KeyListener {

public final static int width = 800;
public final static int height = 400;

private Bird bird;
private Image image,character;
private URL base;
private Graphics second;



public static int getwidth() {
    return width;
}
public static int getheight() {
    return height;
}

@Override
public void init() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.init();
    setSize(width, height);
    setBackground(Color.BLACK);
    setFocusable(true);
    addKeyListener(this);
    Frame frame = (Frame) this.getParent().getParent();
    frame.setTitle("MyApplet");

    try {
        base = getDocumentBase();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
    }
    //Path of your Image
    character = getImage(base, "path to .png image (removed)");
}

@Override
public void start() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.start();
    Thread thread = new Thread(this);
    thread.start();
}

@Override
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(e.getKeyCode()) {
    case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
        bird.resetSpeed();
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_KP_DOWN:
        System.out.println("Do nothing");
        break;
    case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
        bird.resetSpeed();
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    while(true) {
        repaint();
        bird.update();
        try{Thread.sleep(17);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void update(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.update(g);
    if (image == null) {
        image = createImage(this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
        second = image.getGraphics();
    }

    second.setColor(getBackground());
    second.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
    second.setColor(getForeground());
    paint(second);

    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
}


@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    g.drawImage(character, bird.getCenterX(), bird.getCenterY(), null );
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

}
```

Comment: Any reason you're using an applet? They are unsupported.

Comment: Because of the Tutorial i didn't they are unsupported I never programmed Java before just cpp and python, so what would be a good alternative to applet?

Comment: And how do i know if something is supported in java or not

Comment: Use the official [tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/). If you want to learn GUI learn Swing or JavaFX. There were many announcements when applets stopped being supported, but it also comes from the browser developers side. You have to keep up with Java announcements. Don't worry, they come once in a long while.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) In brief, forget applets and AWT, concentrate on frames (`JFrame`) & Swing.